# screen/tmux alternative in java

Tags: java, gnu-screen, tmux

I am getting frequently disconnected from my ssh session due to flaky internet connection, which results in loss of work.
I am using Solaris 10 and screen/tmux is available from sunfreeware.com but, we don't have root access on the machines we are using.
Do we have a java program that can keep ssh sessions alive between connections just like tmux/screen program in linux.
Any advice on installing screen/tmux or similar utilities without root access is also welcome

Comment: If you have the compiler toolchain available on Solaris, just compile it and install it in your `$HOME`, that is not a problem. Unless your home is mounted with noexec, it should just work.

Comment: can I get prebuild binaries that I can run from my home? It would be helpful if you can point me to the right resource.

Comment: I don't think so, precompiled binaires are generally packaged to install on the system itself. Well, that is my experience, but maybe Solaris has a different packaging format allowing for this? No idea.

Comment: @tutysara, how did you solve this? no root access, job gets killed after logging out of ssh. Without access cannot install screen/tmux. This is a RedHat linux machine though.